# Subclassing UITableViewCell correctly?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

What is the difference between adding the subview to self and or to the content view?

Subview added to self

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame { if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@”lol.jpg”]; 
    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img]; 
    [self addSubview:imgView];
    [imgView release]; 
    return self;
}
```

Subview added to contentView

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame { if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@”lol.jpg”]; 
    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img]; 
    [self.contentView addSubview:imgView];
    [imgView release]; 
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

According to the [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006938-CH3-SW18):

> The content view of a UITableViewCell object is the default superview for content displayed by the cell. If you want to customize cells by simply adding additional views, you should add them to the content view so they will be positioned appropriately as the cell transitions into and out of editing mode.

Generally you add to a contentView when you are comfortable with your resizing and positioning of your content being handled by the autoresize settings, and subclass UITableViewCell when you need some custom behavior and such. The Apple Table View Programming Guide has a great section on [customizing UITableViewCells](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW18).

Answer (score 0):

You should alway insert your custom view into the cell `contentView`. Be sure you do not use

```
cell.textLabel?.text
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because when a tableviewcell goes into **editing** mode it will add **other controls** like delete button to the cell. so your content should be resized to make room for the new controls. If you add your subviews directly to the tableviewcell these editing controls would obscure the subviews you added. The cell cannot adjust its size when entering editing mode(it must remain the width of the table view). but the contentView object can and it does. that's why you should add your subviews to the contentView object.