# Is it possible to display UITableViewCellStyleValue1 and UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle within the same row

Tags: ios, uitableview

I would like to display information below and infront of the main content in a row in a table view, is this possible?

Something like...see screenshot.

https://www.evernote.com/shard/s157/sh/b5527a4b-c079-4ca6-9dc8-f9fdc8760816/0d83416b09e8e52ee341bc171a34ad5b

Thanks

Comment: You need a custom cell for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a subclass of UITableViewCell which does this and exposes the correct outlets.

Something like this

```
@interface MyCustomUITableViewCell < UITableViewCell
@property (nonatomic, readonly, weak) UILabel *title;
@property (nonatomic, readonly, weak) UILabel *subtitle;
@property (nonatomic, readonly, weak) UILabel *title;

- (id) initWithReuseIdentifier:(NSString*)identifier;
@end
```

You can create the UI programmatically or you could build the cell as a nib and connect the outlets.

**Note:** Any new UI should be added to the contentView property of the UITableViewCell.

Here are a few similar questions

- [Subclassing UITableViewCell correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368666/subclassing-uitableviewcell-correctly)
- http://blog.giorgiocalderolla.com/2011/04/16/customizing-uitableviewcells-a-better-way/
- http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/customizing-uitableview-cell/ (Shows how you could it using a prototype cell and tags if you don't want to create a sub class.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help I will dig into this a little bit more, thank you for the links.